# Encoding and decoding in Python 2.7.5.1 on windows cmd and pycharm get diffrent result

Tags: python, string, unicode, decode, encode

I use this code to deal with chinese:

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

  strInFilNname = u'%s' % raw_input("input fileName:").decode('utf-8')

  pathName = u'%s' % raw_input("input filePath:").decode('utf-8')
```

When I run this on PyCharm everything is ok. But when I run this on windows CMD, I get this error code:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "E:\Sites\GetAllFile.py", line 23, in <module>
 strInFilNname = u'%s' % raw_input("input filename:").decode('utf-8')
 File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\App\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
 return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

I have read this [python document about Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), but can't get effective  solution.

I really want to know why  it does so .

Comment: Windows Command Prompt doesn't support Unicode output.  Hard stop.  There are various suggestions to work around this (e.g. with `chcp`), but they're clunky at best, often not usable.  The best advice now is to not use it in favor of a console that does support Unicode output (e.g. IDLE, your IDE's console, Powershell, etc.)

Comment: Thanks.But when I use the same code and run **in python 3.3 on CMD ,errors also disappear** ,how come?

Comment: The errors may disappear, but the output won't be correct (won't be the expected unicode output).  You can do some trickery to have the errors disappear (look at `PYTHONIOENCODING` or replacing `sys.stdout`), but even if you do, what is displayed by Windows Command Prompt will not be correct or what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows console encoding is not UTF-8.  I will assume you are using a Chinese-localized version of Windows since you mention the errors go away in Python 3.3 and suggest trying `sys.stdin.encoding` instead of `utf-8`.

Below is an example from my US-localized Windows using characters from the `cp437` code page, which is what the US console uses (Python 2.7.9):

This returns a byte string in the console encoding:

```
>>> raw_input('test? ')
test? │┤╡╢╖╕╣
'\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9'
```

Convert to Unicode:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'cp437'
>>> raw_input('test? ').decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
test? │┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗╝╜╛
u'\u2502\u2524\u2561\u2562\u2556\u2555\u2563\u2551\u2557\u255d\u255c\u255b'
```

Note it prints correctly:

```
>>> print(raw_input('test? ').decode(sys.stdin.encoding))
test? │┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗
│┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗
```

This works correctly for a Chinese Windows console as well as it will use the correct console encoding for Chinese.  Here's the same code after switching my system to use Chinese:

```
>>> raw_input('Test? ')
Test? 我是美国人。
'\xce\xd2\xca\xc7\xc3\xc0\xb9\xfa\xc8\xcb\xa1\xa3'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'cp936'
>>> raw_input('Test? ').decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
Test? 我是美国人。
u'\u6211\u662f\u7f8e\u56fd\u4eba\u3002'
>>> print raw_input('Test? ').decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
Test? 我是美国人。
我是美国人。
```

Python 3.3 makes this much simpler:

```
>>> input('Test? ')
Test? 我是美国人。
'我是美国人。'
```

Comment: Does not work on Win10 pt_BR. `sys.stdin.encoding` returns "utf-8" and decode simply explodes...

Comment: @j4x What Python version are you using?  This is a 4-year-old answer and encodings are very Python and OS-specific.

Comment: Hi @MarkTolonen. It is an ActiveState Python 2.7.14. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: @j4x Using a GUI of any kind?  They can override stdin/out and .encoding may not be correct.